# How to declare a struct defined in a function scope?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a function as such:

```
auto get_struct() {
  struct foo {
    int x;
  };

  return foo{2};
}
```

I can access and use `foo` as such:

```
decltype(get_struct()) fooDecl;
auto x_val = get_struct().x;
```

Is it possible to define `fooDecl` without using `decltype`? And if yes what would the syntax look like?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way besides `decltype`.

Comment: I'm guessing that means declaring `fooDecl` is not possible in C++ 03?

Comment: Which standard are you targetting specifically? This stuff is changing quite a lot at present.

Comment: @crezefire returning local classes is not possible in C++03 anyway. C++11 can already do it with lambdas, and then I don't see a better way than `decltype`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm not targeting any standard, was just experimenting with some stuff and it got me wondering about this.

Comment: By using `auto` and `decltype`, you're implicitly targeting C++11 or later.

Comment: You declare a type locally just so it should not be visible outside. So, No you cannot directly get the name of the struct outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, it is not possible to declare `fooDecl` without `decltype` and not possible pre C++ 11.

Thanks to Quentin & Bo Persson for their comments on the matter.